# What do "a" and "A" cpoptions do, exactly?

Tags: vimrc

From the docs at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'cpoptions':

```
    a   When included, a ":read" command with a file name
        argument will set the alternate file name for the
        current window.

    A   When included, a ":write" command with a file name
        argument will set the alternate file name for the
        current window.
```

I'm confused by what an "alternate file name" is. And if these two options are unset with `cpo-=aA`, how will VIM behave differently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The alternate file is the file you were previously editing in the current window. Each window has its own independent alternate file. Type `:h usr_07.txt`, and look for the pattern `alternate`. You should find this paragraph:

```
The file you were previously editing is called the "alternate" file.  When you
just started Vim CTRL-^ will not work, since there isn't a previous file.
```

You can toggle between the current and alternate files by typing on the command line:

```
:buffer #
```

... or shorter:

```
:b#
```

Or, from normal mode, you can press `<C-^>` (could be the same as `<C-6>`).

---

Suppose you have 3 files A, B, and C. And you launch Vim to edit A:

```
vim A
```

A is your current file, and there's no alternate file.
If you load B (`:edit B`), then A becomes the alternate file, and B becomes the current file. You can toggle between A and B  as many times as you want by repeating `:b#` or `<C-^>`.

If at some point you stop toggling, while your current buffer is B, your alternate file is A, and you ask Vim to edit C (`:edit C`), then the current file will become C, and the alternate file will become B.

From then, `:b#` and `<C-^>` won't make you cycle between A and B anymore, but between B and C.

---

The name of the alternate file is stored inside the `#` register, so you can read it by typing:

```
:echo @#
```

You can also see it when you type `:ls` or `:buffers`. These commands list all the buffers which are loaded in your current session. Inside the listing, the alternate buffer is marked with the `#` sign, while the current buffer is marked with the `%` sign.

---

If the `aA` flags are inside `'cpo'`, then, whenever you execute a command such as `:read some_file` or `:write some_file`, `some_file` will become the alternate file for the current window.

---

To understand what's the effect of the `aA` flags inside `'cpo'`, you could try the following experiment.

Create 2 files inside your `/tmp` folder, named `foo1.txt` and `foo2.txt`. The first one containing the word `hello`, the second one containing `world`:

```
cd /tmp && echo hello >> foo1.txt && echo world >> foo2.txt
```

Open `foo1.txt` with Vim:

```
vim foo1.txt
```

And make sure the `a` flag is not inside the `'cpo'` option, by typing:

```
:set cpo-=a
```

Try to load the alternate file for the current window with `:b#` or `<C-^>`.

The Ex command should have no effect, and the normal command should raise the error:

```
E23: No alternate file
```

In both cases, the buffer displayed in the current window should still be `foo1.txt`.

This result was expected, because there can't be any alternate file for this window, since you've just started Vim.

Now, import the contents of the `foo2.txt` file:

```
:read foo2.txt
```

Your buffer should now contain:

```
hello
world
```

Again, try to load the alternate file with `:b#` or `<C-^>`. The result is still the same.
The `:read` command didn't change / set the alternate file of your current window, because the `a` flag wasn't inside `'cpo'`.

Add the `a` flag to `'cpo'`, and re-import the contents of `foo2.txt`:

```
:set cpo+=a
:r foo2.txt
```

Your buffer should now contain:

```
hello
world
world
```

Finally, try to load the alternate file: `:b#` or `<C-^>`.

This time, `/tmp/foo2.txt` should be displayed in the current window, because the `a` flag is inside `'cpo'`, and so the argument of the previous `:read` command, `/tmp/foo2.txt`, was set as the alternate file of your window.

---

The same thing happens with the `:write` command, and the `A` flag.

You can use the `:write` command to write a range of lines of the current buffer inside another file. For example, you could visually select a paragraph, then type:

```
:'<,'>write /tmp/foo3.txt
```

This should write the visual selection inside `/tmp/foo3.txt`. But if the `A` flag is not inside `'cpo'`, then the alternate file of your current window won't be changed. If `A` is inside `'cpo'`, then `/tmp/foo3.txt` will become the alternate file of your current window.

Comment: Cool, thanks so much. What practical use does this have?

Comment: @StevieD The alternate file is useful when you have to frequently switch between 2 files, but don't want to split the current window. As for the `a` and `A` flags, I suppose they are useful when you find that some `:read` or `:write` commands interfere in your work by setting an alternate file C while you were switching between 2 files A and B. If this happens to you a lot, I guess it would make sense to remove `aA` from `'cpo'`, otherwise you could let them inside.